# Prove why this equality holds

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

[Help in a problem about Lebesgue integration inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1011042/help-in-a-problem-about-lebesgue-integration-inequality)

If the sum is finite there is no problem , but if it is not how i can prove or show that the following happens

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^p\mu(E_n)$ =$\int\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^p\chi_{E_n}$

Also , if someone can help me ending the proof of this problem , it would be apreciated so much

Answer (score 0):

Where are you stuck? Remember that an infinite sum is defined to be the limit of a finite sum...

Comment: If I have the last inequality in the only answer of the problem , then I figured out to do the infinte sum of the members of the inequality and the integrate. I already know the equality I post above is true but I can not explain why this happens.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I missed the link. Use the monotone convergence theorem

Comment: how?  i get the idea but  its not clear at all to me

Answer (score 0):

Apply the monotone convergence theorem to the partial sums of the sum in the integrand.

Comment: Still dont seem clear to me :/

Comment: What does the monotone convergence theorem say?

Comment: a non descrescent sequence of function which converge to a a function f then the integral of the function is the limit of the integral of the sequence converging to f. :/

Comment: All right. What would be the expression for a partial sum?

Comment: the finite sum of n^p mutiplied by the measure of E_n

Comment: No, I meant a partial sum of the sum appearing in the integrand.